# jQuery: Cycle Crossfades + CSS Background Stretching

Tags: jquery, css, cycle

I'm trying to create a slideshow where the images are stretched to the browser's maximum width and height, while performing a crossfade. The problem I'm encountering is that when the user stretches the window, the re-stretching of the background fails most of the time. I suspect it has to do with the way jQuery Cycle redraws during the animation process.

Has anyone else solved this issue using the CSS+Cycle method? My code:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_jquery/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).bind('load', function() {
    $('.kittens li:first').fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $('.kittens').cycle({ delay: 1000 });
        });
});
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<style type="text/css">
html, body { overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.kittens { width: 100%; height: 100% }
.kittens li {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
display: none;
}
.kitten1 { background: url(kitten1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; }
.kitten2 { background: url(kitten2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; }
.kitten3 { background: url(kitten3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; }
</style>
<body>
<ul class="kittens">
<li class="kitten1">Kitten1</li>
<li class="kitten2">Kitten2</li>
<li class="kitten3">Kitten3</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the example I have now:
http://play.meyouand.us/110920-jquery-stretchcycle/test1.html

Comment: I am looking at a lazy solution (avoid it) but why would users resize their window?

Comment: In most cases they wouldn't. But, I have seen some instances where test users realize the background is tailored for their window and begin to stretch their window to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that 100% is really 100% of the viewport. When you change the window-size the browser doesn't redraw/recalculates the 100% width.
What you could do is reload the elements on the page, when the window size becomes larger than the original. 
This should reload the ul/li combo at 100% viewport.

Comment: Good solution! I tried using a location.reload(), but it subsequently also resets the slideshow sequence back to 1. Is there a way to reload specific elements without having to reload the page? What I have so far: http://play.meyouand.us/110920-jquery-stretchcycle/test2.html

Comment: Probably not the best, but you can do: $(window).resize(function() {
        $myKittens = $(".kittens").clone();
        $(".kittens").remove();
        $myKittens.appendTo("body");    
        $('.kittens li:first').fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $('.kittens').cycle({
                    delay: 1000
                });
            });
    });     - You can also check out the https://gist.github.com/740199 Jquery Force redraw